# How much force does a lock's pin have due to the spring?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, springs

I found this [gif](http://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--dsYdp705--/18c7saub4nw9ggif.gif), and I was wondering how much force is applied on the pin due to the spring from the top? Also, is there an industry standard for the amount of force exerted?

[image: lock tumbler animation]

Comment: You know the more the pin deflects the higher the spring force. So there isn't a constant value, but there is a max value depending on the width of the key.

Answer (score 2):

**Hooke's Law**

The force of applied by the spring to the pin, will depend on how much the spring is compressed. This can be calculated by using Hooke's Law:

[image]

**Finding k (Using assumptions)**

In order to find find **k**, for demonstration we will just assume a few properties of the spring based on what we can see in the gif.

[Spring Constant Calculator](http://www.acxesspring.com/spring-constant-calculator.html)

[image]

k = 0.136 N/mm

**Finding X maximum**

For demonstration we will use 3 mm for the maximum compression of the spring.

**Calculating Maximum Force From Spring**

Using the assumed properties and plugging them into Hooke's Law.

F = k X

F = (0.136)*(3)

F = 0.408 N

**Industry Standards**

This type of lock is a **Tumbler Lock** and the spring force is most likely not regulated or standardized in industry, but other contributors may have more information.